# Script only working with .jpg image types, needs to work with .png and .gif also

Tags: jquery, image, types, src

This script tries to replace a thumbnail image with a full size image where available, but currently it only works when the full size image source is a .jpg. I'd like it to work with all image types, or at least .png and .gif files as well.

```
// Now append the merch image, short description, //
// and SKU number to our table cells. //
jQuery.each(merchImage, function (i, val) {
    $(val).appendTo("#mcell" + i);
    var s = $(val).attr('src');
    // get full size image path info //
    var s_chop = s.lastIndexOf("_");
    var s_src = s.substr(0, s_chop);
    // if a full-size image exists, replace thumbnail //
    if (s_src.search(/notavail/i) == -1) {
        s = s_src + '.jpg';
        $(val).attr('src', s);
    }
    $(val).css('width', '').css('height', '').css('max-width', '180px').css('max-height', '240px');
    $("<br />").appendTo("#mcell" + i);
});
});
```

Comment: what you get in `s_src` ?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to know somehow the destination file name so you can use here

```
 s = s_src + '.jpg';
```

other file extensions

```
 s = s_src + '.png';

 s = s_src + '.gif';
```

But if we sure that i.e. your Images folder has only images  and `s_src` is **ALWAYS** correct you can try just use instead of code

```
 if (s_src.search(/notavail/i) == -1) {
        s = s_src + '.jpg';
        $(val).attr('src', s);
    }
```

that one

```
if (s_src.search(/notavail/i) == -1) {

        $(val).attr('src', s_src);
    }
```

but please workaround here

```
var s_chop = s.lastIndexOf("_");
var s_src = s.substr(0, s_chop);
```

so you are  going to keep the file extension in `s_src`.

I hope you are getting the idea in general...

Comment: I tried removing s = s_src + '.jpg'; and adding $(val).attr('src', s_src);  but now it's not working with any pictures